# Different behaviour for Path.toFile() and new File(pathString)

Tags: java, file, java-io, network-drive, java.nio.file

I have mounted a network drive (samba server) in Windows.

I have a file in that drive that I wanted to read in a Java program.

Before I was trying to read the file using:

```
Paths.get(basePath, fileName).toFile()
```

But it was failing with error that file does not exists. The file was there and the path was good.

Then I tried the following code which worked:

```
String path = Paths.get(basePath, fileName).toAbsolutePath().toString()
File file = new File(path)
```

Is there any difference between both approaches? Does it require any security settings?

**Update**

So after I had used the second part (the one that worked), I went back to original (as it was) to verify debugging and this time it worked. I tried it with another file in same directory and it failed. It seems weird but I will check more.

Comment: SMH there is a difference if one method works.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use JCIFS? That way it'd work from any place without the need to have previously mapped the network drive onto the computer....

Comment: What happens if you leave out the call to `toAbsolutePath`? Or add it in the first case?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Windows 7. And the network drive is toward Centos running samba server.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Never heard of it. Will check it

Answer (score 2):

To best understand what is possibly happening I'd recommend debugging through the code. Below I'll explain what could be the issue based on my understanding of the source code.

First of all there is different implementations of `Path` and as you mentioned you're working on Windows so I had a look at the source code for `WindowsPath` which I found [here](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPath.java).

So the method `Path.toFile()` is pretty simple. It is:

```
public final File toFile() {
    return new File(this.toString());
}
```

`this` is referring to the instance of the Path implementation and in the case of Windows it's an implementation of `WindowsPath`.

Looking at the `WindowsPath` class we see `toString()` implemented as follows:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return path;
}
```

Now looking at how this `path` variable is built. The `WindowsPath` class invokes the `WindowsPathParser` class which builds the path. The source for `WindowsPathParser` can be found [here](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPathParser.java).

The `parse` method in `WindowsPathParser` is where you'll need to debug to find out exactly what is happening. Depending on your initial `path` that you pass as a method parameter this method parses that as a different `WindowsPathType` e.g. ABSOLUTE, DIRECTORY_RELATIVE.

The below code shows how the initial `path` input can change the type of `WindowsPathType`

***Code***

```
private static final String OUTPUT = "Path to [%s] is [%s]";

public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    printPathInformation("c:\\dev\\code");
    printPathInformation("\\c\\dev\\code");
}

private static void printPathInformation(String path) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Path windowsPath = Paths.get(path);

    Object type = getWindowsPathType(windowsPath);

    System.out.println(String.format(OUTPUT,path, type));
}

private static Object getWindowsPathType(Path path) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field type = path.getClass().getDeclaredField("type");

    type.setAccessible(true);

    return type.get(path);
}
```

***Output***

```
Path to [c:\dev\code] is [ABSOLUTE]
Path to [\c\dev\code] is [DIRECTORY_RELATIVE]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check your filepaths and maybe imports because this worked fine for me also not sure why your breaking up your path but maybe were talking about 2 different path imports

```
System.out.println("File:"+new File(path).exists());
System.out.println("Path:"+Paths.get(path).toFile().exists());
```

My imports if you want to compare

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

I would say give it a shot with the full path not broken up at all see if anything changes

Comment: The file exists, I print the path and then try to open in Notepad++ and it worked.